# UITabBarController covers view in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, ios10, uitabbar

In an iOS app that I'm working on, the bottom tab bar covers the bottommost part of most views.

My setup is as such:

- App that supports iOS 8 + 9 + 10
- The app uses xibs, not storyboards
- The table view in this example uses auto layout

If I open the settings view in iOS 8 and iOS 9, the view looks like this when scrolled to the bottom:

[image: Entire view is display in iOS 8 + 9]

If I open the same view in iOS 10, it looks like this when scrolled to the bottom:

[image: View is cropped in iOS 10]

iOS 10 will, however, adjust this if I minimize the app and bring it up again, or if I leave the page and later return to it:

[image: Entire view is display in iOS 10]

I tried tinkering with the extended edges of the view. Removing the bottom from this collection made iOS 10 display it properly:

[image: Initial display of view without bottom extended edge]

However, returning to the view now causes a white bar to appear:

[image: White bar when returning to a view with no bottom extended edge]

Also, this bottom edge fix does not work for any sub views.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I will suggest you to rearrange all your XIBs by using a reference of `Bottom Bar` (other than `Inferred`) in `Simulated Matrix` at `Attribute Inceptor` in IB.

Comment: You can give a try with an easy one XIB.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I add a simulated bottom bar, I still have no reference to it, do I? I mean, it's just there for show...you can't base auto sizing on it.

Comment: Just add that simulated bottom bar where it should be. No need to do this on the XIBs which does not have bottom bar in main application. It will arrange the content in actual spacing. I always use it. I never had any issue like you are having.